# CoinBase Rest Api integration in android

Tags: coinbase-api

I hope your are well, I am asking a question how to use REST Coinbase Api in Android. I am searching in whole website no solution to this api. This api is not used in Postman. Github coinbase SDK is too old. Using this API in postman but no response in Postman. Please help me for this api.

Thanks 
Mukesh Singh

Comment: What i exactly your issue? what is failing? I have a fully working environment working

Answer (score 1):

Check the version 2 of the Coinbase API:

https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2

It works, make sure you use the keys when try to make a request.